# How to add nodes inside admin area, e.g. for admin documentation

Tags: nodes, theming

I have an admin theme set. When I create a page in my custom module with an `admin/...` path it is rendered with the admin theme.

I've set up a node type for documentation and I'd like these to be inside the admin area. I've set the default menu to *Management* and I've given the page an alias that begins with `admin/` but it's rendered in the normal (non-admin) theme.

How can I add nodes that will be considered part of the admin area, and rendered with the admin theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [Administration theme](https://drupal.org/project/admin_theme) module:

> The Administration theme module allows you to use this theme on more pages like :
>
> - batch processing pages
> - devel node load and render pages
> - coder code review pages
> - **pages you define yourself** in the provided textarea

Emphasis mine.